# Java Array parsing

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I have read a file into an array but am wondering how to parse certain values from that array.

My code:

```
        ...
        try{
             ...
             String strLine;
             String delims= "[ ]+";
             //parsing it
             ArrayList parsedit = new ArrayList();
             while((strLine=br.readLine())!=null){
                 System.out.println("Being read:");
                 System.out.println(strLine);
                 parsedit.add(strLine.split(delims));
             }
             System.out.println("Length:" + parsedit.size());
             in.close();   
             ...
```

The files that I am reading in are like this:

```
a b c d e f g
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 4 5 6 3 5 7
1 4 6 7 3 2 5
```

Which makes the output like this:

```
How many files will be input? 1
Hey, please write the full path of the input file number1! 
/home/User/Da/HA/file.doc
Being read:
a b c d e f g 
Being read:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
...
Length:4
```

I would like to parse out this data and just have the first and fifth values remaining, so that it would read like this instead:

```
a e
1 5
```

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to go about it? 
EDIT:
Following some of the suggestions I have changed my code to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("How many files will be input? ");
        Scanner readIn=new Scanner(System.in);
        int input=readIn.nextInt();
        int i=1;
        while(i<=input){
            System.out.println("Hey, please write the full path of the input file number" + i + "! ");
            Scanner fIn=new Scanner(System.in);
            String fileinput=fIn.nextLine();
          try{
             FileInputStream fstream=new FileInputStream(fileinput);
             DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(fstream);
             BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
             String strLine;
             String delims= "[ ]+";
             ArrayList parsedit = new ArrayList();
             while((strLine=br.readLine())!=null){
                 System.out.println("Being read:");
                 System.out.println(strLine);
                 parsedit.add(strLine.split(delims));
             }
             String[] splits=strLine.split(delims);
             System.out.println("Length:" + splits.length);
             in.close();   
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        i++;
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't give back any errors but it doesn't seem to be working all the same. Am I missing something silly? The output is this:

```
How many files will be input? 1
Hey, please write the full path of the input file number1! 
/home/User/Da/HA/file.doc
Being read:
a b c d e f g 
Being read:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
...
```

But despite the fact that I have a line to tell me the array length, it never gets printed, which tells me I just ended up breaking more than I fixed. Do you know what it is that I may be missing/forgetting?

Comment: Instead of `BufferedReader.readLine()` you could try using `BufferedReader.read()` to read character by character to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html Its more confusing than useful.

Comment: @PeterLawrey What would you recommend instead?

Comment: Remove it, you don't need it.  For a better alternative use FileReader as suggested in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split()` function returns an array of strings representing the tokens obtained from the original String.

So, what you want is to keep only the first and the 5th token (splits[0] & splits[4]):

```
  String[] splits = strLine.split(delims); 
  //use the splits[0] & splits[4] to create the Strings you want
```

Regarding your update, replace this:

```
 while((strLine=br.readLine())!=null){
             System.out.println("Being read:");
             System.out.println(strLine);
             parsedit.add(strLine.split(delims));
 }
```

With this:

```
 while((strLine=br.readLine())!=null){
             System.out.println("Being read:");
             String splits[] = strLine.split(delims);
             System.out.println(splits[0]+" "+splits[4]);
             parsedit.add(splits);
 }
```

Comment: I changed your `splits[5]` to `splits[4]`, and apparently destroyed your concurrent edit. Sorry.

Comment: This would go after the "parsedit.add(strLine.split(delims));" line?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. splits = strLine.splits(delims) returns the array of strings. => splits = {a,b,c,d,e...} , for the next line splits = {1,2,3,4...} and so on

Comment: I am horribly sorry, but I am not sure I understand. Do you mind if I update my question so I can get further help?

Comment: The question has been updated. If you et a chance to have another look I would be more than grateful. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
String[] line = s.split("\\s+");
```

This way all your elements will be stored in a sequence in the array `line`.
This will allow you to access whatever element you want.

Comment: Are you suggesting doing this instead of: parsedit.add(strLine.split(delims)); ?

Comment: what i am suggesting is to read the entire page into the String s. and then split the characters of string into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the first and the fifth value out of the `String[]` returned by `strLine.split(delims)`.

(I am assuming you know what you are doing in your current code. You are assuming that each line will contains the same number of "columns", delimited by at least 1 space character. It is a fair assumption, regardless.)

Comment: But how do you recommend going about getting the first and the fifth value?

Comment: @User: The `split()` function returns an array, which you can get the 1st and 5th value @ index 0 and 4.